# iFrame not displaying once I publish site live, but works locally

Tags: iframe, bootstrap-4

My iFrame will not display the contents once it is published, but works fine locally.

Any ideas what is causing this?

Comment: Please don't post images with stack traces. Instead copy the traces directly into StackOverflow and use the Markup Language to mark it properly

Answer (score 1):

In bootstrap
iframes are not allowed by default. You'll need to add exceptions for them with the sanitizer. see https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/javascript/#sanitizer White listening iFrames is the way to go.
If thats not the cause it maybe going cross-site or cross-loading bootstrap. Had some weird errors with bootstrap.js since browsers enforce security.